# Remove windows 10 in ubuntu dual boot

Tags: software-uninstall

Have been searching all over the internet on how to to remove Windows 10 from dual boot but all i get is answers that are not very clear to me on what to do.I have been using Ubuntu for like 5 months now and my Windows 10 is having glitches,that's why i'd like to uninstall it,without deleting files like music,pictures and videos.Also is there some other ways if i dont have a bootable CD? Am using an Acer Aspire V5. Kindly help me out.Thank you.

Comment: @Imran Athman karel is right.

Comment: Thanks alot guys...Big time